# INLotSerialNbrAttribute Error: must implement the PX.Objects.IN.ILSMaster interface

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use the INLotSerialNbrAttribute on my custom screen.  I get below error message.  I think it must have something to do with some screens using the split function.  For my screen I just want to allow a single Serial Number per line similar to the adjustment screen.  Do I need to add something on my graph to handle this or should I create my own selector?

Here's the definition of my DAC field

```
    #region LotSerialNbr
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lot Serial Nbr")]
    [INLotSerialNbr(typeof(AHSVendorCoreDetails.inventoryID), 
    typeof(AHSVendorCoreDetails.subItemID), typeof(AHSVendorCoreDetails.locationID), 
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    public virtual string LotSerialNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class lotSerialNbr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<lotSerialNbr> { }
    #endregion
```

> [PXArgumentException: IN Error: The specified type
> AHSVendorCore.AHSVendorCoreDetails must implement the
> PX.Objects.IN.ILSMaster interface. Parameter name: itemType]
> PX.Data.PXCacheCollection.get_Item(Type key) +1547
> PX.Data.PXGraph.GetStateExt(String viewName, Object data, String
> fieldName) +383    PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.bk() +345    PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.d()
> +64    PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.InitColumnsLayout() +262    PX.Web.UI.PXGrid.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean
> dataBinding) +498
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
> +230    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +130    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +66
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +297
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> +7479

***Edit***
Here's the definition of the grid columns.

```
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LineNbr" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="InventoryID" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranDesc" Width="280" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UOM" Width="72" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReturnQty" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="SiteID" Width="140" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LocationID" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LotSerialNbr" Width="220" /></Columns></px:PXGridLevel></Levels></px:PXGrid></Template></px:PXTabItem></Items>
```

***Edit 2***
Here's the updated version with the row template showing the lot serial field is a selector.  I'm still getting the same issue.

```
                    <px:PXGrid SyncPosition="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXGrid2" Height="473px" SkinID="Details" Width="100%" DataSourceID="">
                        <Levels>
                            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="Details" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LineNbr" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="InventoryID" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="TranDesc" Width="280" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UOM" Width="72" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReturnQty" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn CommitChanges="True" DataField="SiteID" Width="140" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LocationID" Width="70" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LotSerialNbr" Width="220" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
                                <RowTemplate>
                                    <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector12" DataField="LotSerialNbr" ></px:PXSelector>
                                    <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit13" DataField="LineNbr" />
                                    <px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="CstPXSegmentMask14" DataField="InventoryID" />
                                    <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit15" DataField="TranDesc" />
                                    <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector16" DataField="UOM" />
                                    <px:PXNumberEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXNumberEdit17" DataField="ReturnQty" />
                                    <px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="CstPXSegmentMask18" DataField="SiteID" />
                                    <px:PXSegmentMask runat="server" ID="CstPXSegmentMask19" DataField="LocationID" /></RowTemplate></px:PXGridLevel></Levels></px:PXGrid>
```

Comment: You do not need PXUIField attribute since the INLotSerialNbr already provides this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to make sure your DAC implements the ILSMaster interface and related fields. If not fully needed just make all required fields Non db fields (Ex: PXInt vs PXDBInt) with unbound defaults to provide some default information. For example InvtMult helps determine if receipt or issue transaction and you can have it default to -1, 0, or 1 depending on your requirements.

Ex:

```
public class AHSVendorCoreDetails : PX.Data.IBqlTable, ILSMaster
{
// Include all required fields from ILSMaster (can be bound or unbound fields)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Brendan, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I added the implementation for the ILSMaster interface and added the required fields to the DAC.  It compiles and runs fine, but I do not get a selector on LotSerial field.  Any idea what I could be missing.  Thanks Scott

Comment: in your page are you using PXSelector for the control? Also in your entry do you have InventoryID entered and committed do your dac row?

Comment: It's a grid column, it shows the same in the aspx as other columns where a selector is showing up.  I'll update my post with the grid columns definition.  I do have a inventory id entered and committed.

Comment: Even for a grid you can define your RowTemplate which is where you tell its a PXSelector. Look at the inventory transaction pages (IN3010000 for example)

Comment: @ScottS maybe you do not have the supporting LSMaster fields. Create and do not release an IN adjustment transaction and look in the DB at the related fields such as InvtMult to make sure your fields are set the same. I think the attribute works differently depending on issue vs receipt.

Comment: good note.  I looked in the db saw the TranType was "ADJ" and InvtMult was 1.  I changed my default values in my ILSMaster implementation and now the Lot Serial field is enabled and the selector works.  Although it seems that like on new grid rows the selected is pulling matching serial numbers from the previous row.  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @ScottS good to hear. If this resolved your issue do not forget to confirm the answer to close the question. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, everything seems good now.  I had to update some of the properties on the grid to make everything refresh properly.  Thanks again.